# Opt out of Customer Experience Improvement Program - but says setting is managed by system admin

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I am currently unable to change the settings for the Windows 7 Customer Experience Improvement Program because it states: "This setting is managed by your system administrator."

I am the ONLY user on my system, I have always been the only user. My user is an administrator. I have tried running Control Panel as an administrator, but it did nothing.

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium, so I do not have access to any Group Policy editor (gpedit.msc).

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot into safe mode? If you can do that then you will have an admin user account. Then try to do the same steps.